# How to get utf-8 api response content in android

Tags: android, utf-8, character-encoding

EDIT:
Thanks to some awnsers I edited my method to this, but still not gettign rid of the ? marks.

```
 public String makeHttpGetRequestUtf8(String urlStr) throws IOException {
    String result = "";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        //BufferedReader brIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8")); //<--- Tried this first but didn't help.
        BufferedReader brIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); //<-- This also didn't help :(

        String line = "";
        while ((line = brIn.readLine()) != null)
            result += line;
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("HTT_GET", "Failed to make httpGetRequestUtf8: " + e);
    }
    String afterDecode = URLDecoder.decode(result, "UTF-8");
    return afterDecode;
}
```

In android I have tried two httpGet methods to get the response of an api. Both return me the content with question marks in them, meaning no utf-8 support.

The same api call on browser returns UTF-8 supported text.
The response is in json.

httpGet 1:

```
public String makeHttpGetRequest(String urlStr) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(urlStr);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream());
    String response = readUntilEndOfStream(isr);
    isr.close();
    return response;
}

private String readUntilEndOfStream(InputStreamReader isr) throws IOException {
    StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();
    int character = isr.read();
    while (character != END_OF_STREAM) {
        data.append((char) character);
        character = isr.read();
    }
    return data.toString();
}
```

This returns the response with question marks.

httpGet 2:

```
 public String makeHttpGetRequestUtf8(String urlStr) throws IOException {
    String result = "";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream isr = con.getInputStream();

        // convert inputstream to string
        if(isr != null)
            result = convertInputStreamToString(isr);
        else
            result = "Could not make httpGetResul success";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return result;
}

// convert inputstream to String
private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;

    inputStream.close();
    return result;

}
```

Same story here.

I think there is some principle mistake I am making with there encoding issues.
Thanks for any hint.

Comment: you can try `URLDecoder() `..

Comment: Added the UrlDecode to questions edit, still nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

To convert the InputStream you could use something like this :

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

or in java 7 you can do

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

EDIT :

You can also try to use an InputStreamReader (it will detect the encoding of the HTTP response):

```
String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

If it does not works, maybe you need to set the encoding in the response before :

```
response.setContentType("text/html");    
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried both but neither didn't work. Still getting error. I added the new method I changed to the questions edit as well.

Comment: I am not getting an error, but the result string has question marks in it.
Example: "�ldelektrit��d koos infotehnoloogia kaabeldusega teostatud..."

Comment: What are those "?" char supposed to be ?

Comment: Here are the characters that are shown as ? mark: 'ä', 'õ', 'ö', 'ü'